# set alias for `model` hook

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

HELP

If there is a `model` hook in `app/routes/post.js` say

```
model() {
  return this.store.query('post');
}
```

in `template` the returned promised is accessed using

```
{{#each model as |post|}}
  ...
{{/each}}
```

Is there any way to set `alias` for the model? Something like this in `route` or `controller`?

`posts: alias('model')`

So I can access the returned promise in the template as

```
{{#each posts as |post|}}
  ...
{{/each}}
```

Is this something which is already present or something that got missed from ember documentation?

Comment: https://github.com/ember-cli/eslint-plugin-ember/blob/master/docs/rules/alias-model-in-controller.md

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can create `alias` for model property in your controller,

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { alias } from '@ember/object/computed';

export default Controller.extend({
  posts: alias('model')
})
```

or using `setupController` in your `route`,

```
export default Route.extend({
  setupController(controller, model) {
    controller.set('posts', model);
  },
});
```

Reference:

alias api documentation - [alias computed property](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/functions/@ember%2Fobject%2Fcomputed/alias)

alias your model - [alias-model-rule](https://github.com/ember-cli/eslint-plugin-ember/blob/master/docs/rules/alias-model-in-controller.md)

Comment: notice: overwriting `setupController` will not create an alias but *not set the `model` property at all.

Comment: I would recommend to use `readOnly` instead of `alias`. In that case you also guard against overriding model by accident.